How to properly secure harden SSH in 2024?
Since 1995, SSH, notably OpenSSH server [1999], is one of those essential services like DNS [1985] for admins to manage their IT landscapes.
How do I properly secure harden an OpenSSH server in 2024?

Debian 12 with OpenSSH_9.2, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023

Applied all recommendations, passing the standard test and failing the "hardened" test, saying:

it does not like using kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
the server is using 8192 bits instead of 4096 (more being better?) 




sshd_config:
# Ports and Addresses:
  ## it is (probably) advisable to change this to something else but nothing
  ## beyond 1024 privileged ports?
  ## https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html

#Port                            = 22
#AddressFamily                   = any
#ListenAddress                   = 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress                   = ::

Include                         = /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

# Logging
  ## it is disabled per default on Debian maybe because of brute force attacks
  ## spamming the logs?

SyslogFacility                  = AUTH
LogLevel                        = INFO

# Authentication:
Protocol                        = 2
StrictModes                     = yes
LoginGraceTime                  = 3m
MaxAuthTries                    = 3
ClientAliveInterval             = 300
ClientAliveCountMax             = 2

PermitRootLogin                 = no
PermitEmptyPasswords            = no
PubkeyAuthentication            = yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication    = no
UsePAM                          = no

## not so sure about this one
ChallengeResponseAuthentication = no

## this has no effect?
PasswordAuthentication          = no

## good practice, but is it enough?
AllowUsers                      = username

X11Forwarding                   = no
PrintMotd                       = no
AcceptEnv LANG                  = LC_*
X11Forwarding                   = no

# override default of no subsystems
### Subsystem sftp                  = /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Ciphers and keying
KexAlgorithms                   = sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,gss-curve25519-sha256-,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,gss-group16-sha512-,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers                         = chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs                            = hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you mean by "it does not like using", and what are you using to test? For example, a quick google finds that ssh-audit recently updated to support kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com. We can't answer broad questions like "how to harden ssh", because it depends on your clients, environment, and/or opinion.

This is not a secure sshd_config due to chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com which is exploitable. LoginGraceTime should be short, such as 30 [seconds], and keys shouldn't be higher than 2048 (a higher key severely throttles throughput with no additional security benefit since 2048 in uncrackable and will remain so for quite some time) - here's a pre-built, hardened sshd_config.

Changing the port of SSH is does not change your security posture in the slightest.  Security through obscurity is NOT security. Besides, it is an absolutely trivial process to determine what services exist on a public facing server.

Your problem might be the same as in the bug-report
Unknown algorithm: kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com #228.
If it's the same, then support for it was supposedly added on Dec 20, 2023 in
ssh-audit v3.1.0.

thanks for all productive comments for example, is it correct, that Debian and other distros run sshd as root? service ssh start ps uax|grep sshd root sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups would it not be better to run it as the user "sshd" that gets created during install? PS: yes chaning port of a service is not exactly helping much with securing it but 22 is simply the first port getting scanned = avoid traffic?
